# MS Access - SQL Concatenate works - VBA does not

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, concatenation

I created a query to concatenate two fields in a table into a third field in the same table.

- Table: `[mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups]`
- Field1: `[Product_Group_Code__c]`
- Field2: `[Subcategory_Group_Code__c]`
- Field1&2: `[CCat_PrdGrpCd_n_SubCatCd]`

The query worked, here is the SQL code:

```
UPDATE mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups SET mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups.CCat_PrdGrpCd_n_SubCatCd = [Product_Group_Code__c] & "_" & [Subcategory_Group_Code__c];
```

I used [AllenBrowne's code](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html)
to convert the SQL code to VBA.

But when I pasted the VBA code into a VBA module and ran it and nothing happened. I did not receive any error messages but neither were the two columns concatenated.

```
Sub Test()

strSql = "UPDATE mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups SET mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups.CCat_PrdGrpCd_n_SubCatCd = [Product_Group_Code__c] & ""_"" & [Subcategory_Group_Code__c];"

End Sub
```

I tried looking for other examples on the web and on this site but nothing worked for me.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting any errors because it does not exist. It is working fine what you told to do. I guess you want to run query assigned in the variable `strSql` ?

In that case, you need to do it like below :

```
Sub Test()

    strSql = "UPDATE mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups SET mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups.CCat_PrdGrpCd_n_SubCatCd = [Product_Group_Code__c] & ""_"" & [Subcategory_Group_Code__c];"

    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

End Sub
```

Comment: They would also need to fix the concatenation issue.

Comment: Md. Suman Kabir suggested I add the following to my code: 

DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

The code now looks like this:

Sub test()

strSql = "UPDATE mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups SET mif_999_sf_item_creation_subcategory_groups.CCat_PrdGrpCd_n_SubCatCd = [Product_Group_Code__c] & ""_"" & [Subcategory_Group_Code__c];"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSql

End Sub

This is the ANSWER. Works perfect. Thanks Md. Suman Kabir

Comment: Just curious. I thought I had converted the code from SQL to VBA. So why did I need to use DoCmd.RunSQL?

Comment: Because you need to tell the access db engine to run this sql. When you are running the query from ms access, you click a RUN button, right? Similarly when you are putting this into VBA, you need to tell the engine to run it.

Comment: I really appreciate the support and info. Thanks